# AngularJS: orderBy

Tags: angularjs, sql-order-by

So i have got a ng-repeat with some names in it. What i want to do is following.
The names that are outputted to the screen are ordered alphabetically.

> `<div ng-repeat="n in names | orderBy:'name'"></div>`
>
> - Anne
> - Jane
> - John
> - Mike
> - Ziggy

But is it possible to always show the name 'Mike' as the top name and order the rest alphabetically?

> - Mike
> - Anne
> - Jane
> - John
> - Ziggy

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write additional sorting function for this. For example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names | orderBy:[egoSort, 'name']">{{n}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.egoSort = function(name) {
    return name === 'Mike' ? '' : name;
};
```

This is possible because `orderBy` allows you to specify several predicates using array notation.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FfpcjJBBMm52A71Pa01m?p=preview

Comment: Yes thanks. It works exactly how i want it to be! But can you explain how it works and what you did ?

Comment: You can specify multiple predicate expression by using array. If you define a function, this function must return a value to be compared with other values. We know that name "Mike" must come the first, an what string compared with *any* other string will be less or equal? - empty string. If the first predicate leaves two values in ambiguous state (they are equal), then the next one if used, in our case usual alphabetical comparison.

Comment: hey, Sorry i got another question regarding this problem. What if ur array is something like this.

    `$scope.names = [
        {first:"Anne"},
        {first:"Ziggy"},
        {first:"Jimmy"},
        {first:"Mike"},
        {first:"Liesbet"}
    ];`

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way...

add an attribute say `order` to the user Object which you want to appear at top.

`var specificUserName = {name: Mike,order:0}` //This name would appear first in the list

HTML would be

`<div ng-repeat="n in names | orderBy:['order', 'name']">{{n}}</div>`