# AngularJS orderby : keep an element of array on top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have searched and don't found an answer to my question. Hope, I've well searched !
So, this is my problem :

```
<div id="{{expression.comment_id.$id}}" class="comments" ng-repeat="expression in expressions| orderBy:orderProp"
```

So, orderBy works great, but I have a specific need :
expression.comment_id with '0' id must stay on top.

How can do this ?
I think I must use a personnal filter but I'm not sure this is the more efficient solution.
If this is a good way, how can I implement it correctly ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25910045/949476 In your case your custom function would return `''` if `comment_id === 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look. So I've not well searched :-(

Comment: Well it's not easy to express what you are trying to do for search query. Also check Sameer Shemna's answer.

Answer (score 2):

here you go made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/81q9jwg9/

basically you have to make a custom orderBy filter:

```
<ul ng-repeat="expression in expressions | orderBy:myValueFunction">
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.myValueFunction = function(expression) {
        if(expression.comment_id == 0){
            return expression.comment_id;
        }else{
            return expression.orderProp;
        }
    }
```