# Filtering is not working on Array of objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have list of products as array of object. Want to display that based on highest views count. I tried to use "orderBy" service. But it's not filtering from my attached array of object. Any suggestion about how to do that?

```js
vm.products = [
      {
        title : 'ABC',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '183',
        clicksCount: '34'
      },
      {
        title : 'DEF',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '158',
        clicksCount: '30'
      },
      {
        title : 'GHI',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '86',
        clicksCount: '32'
      },  
      {
        title : 'JKL',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '47',
        clicksCount: '20'
      },
      {
        title : 'MNO',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '62',
        clicksCount: '22'
      }
    ];
```

```html
<md-list>
 <md-list-item layout="row" layout-align="space-between center"
  ng-repeat="product in vm.products | orderBy:'product.viewsCount'" 
    ng-click="vm.latestSelectedIndex = $index; vm.selectProduct(product)"  
  ng-show="!$first">
  <div flex="80">
   <h3 class="product-title">{{product.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product-views" flex="20">
   <div class="count">{{product.viewsCount}}</div>
   <div class="count-label"> Views </div>
  </div>
 </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: It may be because viewCount values are strings, so its sorting them alphabetically so to speak, rather than numerically

Comment: I converted it into number. Now it's working. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to mention products, just use the fieldName

```
<md-list-item layout="row" layout-align="space-between center"
        ng-repeat="product in vm.products | orderBy:'viewsCount'"
```

**EDIT:**

Also the property **`viewsCount`** is a string, you need to parse it as a number/float value as follows.

```
angular.forEach(vm.products, function (detail) {
  detail.viewsCount = parseFloat(detail.viewsCount);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngMaterial'])
 app.controller('productsController',function(){
vm =this;
vm.products = [
      {
        title : 'ABC',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '183',
        clicksCount: '34'
      },
      {
        title : 'DEF',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '158',
        clicksCount: '30'
      },
      {
        title : 'GHI',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '86',
        clicksCount: '32'
      },  
      {
        title : 'JKL',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '47',
        clicksCount: '20'
      },
      {
        title : 'MNO',
        imgSrc: '../../images/product1.png',
        viewsCount: '62',
        clicksCount: '22'
      }
    ];
    
angular.forEach(vm.products, function (detail) {
  detail.viewsCount = parseFloat(detail.viewsCount);
});
    });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
 <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<body ng-app ="mainApp" ng-controller="productsController as vm">
<md-list>
 <md-list-item layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" ng-repeat="product in vm.products | orderBy:'viewsCount'" 
    ng-click="vm.latestSelectedIndex = $index; vm.selectProduct(product)"  
  ng-show="!$first">
  <div flex="80">
   <h3 class="product-title">{{product.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product-views" flex="20">
   <div class="count">{{product.viewsCount}}</div>
   <div class="count-label"> Views </div>
  </div>
 </md-list-item>
</md-list>
</body>
```

Comment: check the demo! i.e because your viewCount is a string and you need to parse to a flot/number

Comment: It's working. But is there any way to start filtering from 2nd index of object? It would be very much helpful......

Comment: just remove the first object from array and apply the filter on controller. mark if the answer helped

Comment: I don't want to lose data. Any other way to do that without actually removing it?

Comment: in that case you need custom orderby filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572508/angularjs-orderby-keep-an-element-of-array-on-top